# How to create Google maps polyline with 2 separate stroke colors running the same path?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not sure how to explian this in text. But hey it goes

Imagine this is a regular red polyline: (top to bottom and R equals red)

```
RR
RR
RR
RR
RR
```

how do you create a polyline like this (R is red G is green)

```
RG
RG
RG
RG
RG
```

does that make sense? Half is red half is green.

What's the best way to go about it?

I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an icon to the polyline and cause it to repeat every 1px it's will basically draw a new line next to it just set the fill color to red and your good to go

Comment: Yes that is correct and that's what I ended up doing anyway. Thank you!